# shopify python api: how do add new assets to published theme?

Tags: python, shopify

The shopify docs are horrible, I couldn't find any info on adding new assets to an existing shopify store.

We're developing an app that needs to add some css and liquid files.

Can someone here can shed some light on how to achieve this simple task?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
asset = shopify.Asset()
asset.key = "templates/josh.liquid"
asset.value = "{% comment %} Liquid is cool {% endcomment %}"
success = asset.save()
```

Be careful; if an asset already exists with the same key then it will be overwritten. You can find out more from the [Asset API documentation.](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/asset#update)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your css in the assets folder and link it in the .liquid file with this:

```
{{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Comment: I would like to add the css and liquid after app installation not manully

Answer (score 0):

simpler way

```
shopify.Asset.create({
    'key' : 'provide-key',
    'value' : 'provide-value'
})
```

shopify docs are virtually non-existent, but going through `pyactiveresource` can help. [here](https://github.com/Shopify/pyactiveresource/tree/master/pyactiveresource)